# Animate an UV sphere with (4D?) noise

Tags: c#, perlin-noise, procedural-generation

I am using a C# port of [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/) with XNA (I know it's dead) to generate planets.

There is a [function](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial8.html) in libnoise that receives the coordinates of a vertex in a sphere surface (latitude and longitude) and returns a random value (from -1 to 1).

So with that value, I can change the height of each vertex on the surface of the sphere (the altitude), creating some elevation, simulating the surface of a planet (I'm not simply wrapping a texture around the sphere, I'm actually creating each vertex from scratch).

An example of what I have:

[image]

Now I want to animate the sphere, [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyGfGAEwIVg)

But the thing is, libnoise only works with 3D noise. 
The "planet" function maps the latitude and longitude to XYZ coordinates of a cube.

And I believe that, to animate a sphere like I want to, I need an extra coordinate there, to be the "time" dimension. Am I right? Or is it possible to do this with what libnoise offers?

OBS: As I mentioned, I'm using an UV sphere, not an icosphere or a spherical cube.

EDIT: Here is the algorithm used by libnoise to map lat/long to XYZ:

```
public double GetValue(double latitude, double longitude) {           

    double x=0, y=0, z=0;

    double PI = 3.1415926535897932385;
    double DEG_TO_RAD = PI / 180.0;

    double r = System.Math.Cos(DEG_TO_RAD * lat);

    x = r * System.Math.Cos(DEG_TO_RAD * lon);
    y = System.Math.Sin(DEG_TO_RAD * lat);
    z = r * System.Math.Sin(DEG_TO_RAD * lon);

    return GetNoiseValueAt(x, y, z);

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you just need a height map that varies over time or do you need terrain with arches, caves, etc that cannot be describe with a height map alone?

Comment: At this point, just the height map that varies over time. As long as x/y are mapped to lat/long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I made it.

I just added the time parameter to the mapped XYZ coordinates.

Using the same latitude and longitude but incrementing time by 0.01d gave me a nice result.

Here is my code:

```
public double GetValue(double latitude, double longitude, double time) {           

    double x=0, y=0, z=0;

    double PI = 3.1415926535897932385;
    double DEG_TO_RAD = PI / 180.0;

    double r = System.Math.Cos(DEG_TO_RAD * lat);

    x = r * System.Math.Cos(DEG_TO_RAD * lon);
    y = System.Math.Sin(DEG_TO_RAD * lat);
    z = r * System.Math.Sin(DEG_TO_RAD * lon);

    return GetNoiseValueAt(x + time, y + time, z + time);

}
```

If someone has a better solution please share it!

Answer (score 1):

An n dimensional noise function takes n independent inputs (i<sub>0</sub>, i<sub>1</sub>, ..., i<sub>n-1</sub>, i<sub>n</sub>) & returns a value v, thus 3D noise is sufficient to generate a height map that varies over time. In your case the inputs would be longitude, latitude & time and the output would be the height offset.

The simple general algorithm would be:

```
at each time step (t){
  for each vertex (v) on a sphere centered on some point (c){
    calculate the longitude & latitude
    get the scalar noise value (n) for the longitude, latitude & time
    calculate the new vertex position (p) as follows p = ((v-c)n)+c
  }
}
```

Note: this assumes you are not replacing/modifiying the original vertex values.  You could either save a copy of them (uses less computation, but more memory) or recalculate them them based on a distance from c (uses less memory, but more computation).  Also, you might get a smoother animation by calculating 2 (or more) larger time steps & interpolating to get the intermediate frames.

To the best of my knowledge, this solution should work for a UV sphere, an icosphere or a spherical cube.

Comment: Then I think I can't do it with libnoise, I edited my question with the code used by libnoise to map lat/long to XYZ. What I can understand from it is that, they get the values straight out of a "cube", so the borders can seamlessly connect. Where would the third "time" parameter fit in that function?

Comment: Presumably, time would wrap, such that the animation would loop in a seamless manner.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer elsewhere online, so I'm writing this up for anyone who has this problem in the future.

What worked for me was using multiple 3d perlin noise sources, and combining them into 1 single noise source. Adding time to the xyz coordinates just creates a very noticeable effect of terrain moving in the (-1,-1,-1) direction.
Averaging over 4 uncorrelated noise sources does change the noise characteristics a bit, so you might have to adapt some factors to your use case.
This solution still isn't perfect, but I haven't seen any visual artifacts.

Code is C++ libnoise, but it should translate equally well to other languages.

```
noise::module::Perlin perlin_noise[4];

float get_height(ofVec3f p, float time) {
    p*=2;
    time /= 10 ;
    return (perlin_noise[0].GetValue(p.x, p.y, p.z) +
            perlin_noise[1].GetValue(p.x, p.y, time) +
            perlin_noise[2].GetValue(p.x, time, p.z) +
            perlin_noise[3].GetValue(time, p.y, p.z))/2;
}
```

Ideally, for a single 3d noise source, you want to multiply you x,y,z coords with a monotonic function of t, such that it explores a constantly expanding sphere surface of the noise source, but I haven't figured out the math yet..

Edit: the framework I use (openframeworks) has a 4d perlin noise function built in `ofSignedNoise(glm::vec4)`